# Same Mysql Server Cache settings on two different servers, but different result

Tags: mysql, caching, mysql-5.6

I have 2 VPS running MYSQL 5.6 as a DB Server, and both have the cache enabled with the below settings

```
have_query_cache = YES
query_cache_type = ON
query_cache_size = 16777216
query_cache_limit = 1048576   
query_cache_min_res_unit = 4096
query_cache_wlock_invalidate = OFF
```

Normally cache is working on both servers but interestingly there is 1 query that caches on one of the servers but could not on 2nd server.

Need to understand what i am missing in the configurations etc.

Comment: So many things could be effecting this. One would have to be alot closer to the actual server to be able to be of much help here

Comment: @RiggsFolly Just for a clue what are those things that need to consider ?

Comment: At last figure out the issue, the issue was with query it self , please see my solution in the question part.

Comment: I have requested a Re-Open of the question. You can then post your own answer

Comment: Ok so if you now post your solution as an Answer, other will see it more clearly, and you can even accept it and I think get reps for that in the normal way

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 1):

Such issue might have different reasons like different OS, MYSQL versions or in individual query itself.

I just break the query and take the small portion and run the query and simultaneously check the cache hit using *SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Qcache%';* I realised that i am comparing the number with string in IF Statement that does not allow the query to be put in cache. IF( '2,000.00' = 0, 1, 2) does not allow to Cache the query.